# PostgreSQL - query column that has city, state, country for another column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database with a column that has geographical location data like this:

```
party_no   ...misc_cols_in_between...               loc_reverse_geoloc_adr
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
013             ...data...                 367 Cleta Tunnel, South Moriahton, Palestinian Territory
666             ...data...                 NULL
185             ...data...                 Schillerstraße 50-50, 08340, Schwarzenberg/Erzgeb., Sachsen, DE
267             ...data...                 18701-18999 N County Road 2500E, Oakland, IL, 61943, US
389             ...data...                 Le Rocher-Percé, Québec, CA
666             ...data...                 94531, Antioch, CA, US
185             ...data...                 76 Willochra Rd, Salisbury Plain, South Australia, 5109, AU
```

As you can see, now all the geographical location data is the same format. I basically need to run multiple queries with one of them being for example, the max appearing city,state,country and to what party number its linked to.

Would wildcards using LIKE % be the best bet here? I'm thinking I need somewhere to parse out the data in the column on the comma delimiter, since it seems the city , state, and country are delimited by columns. However, sometimes the address is missing and the data isn't formatted the same at all times.

Comment: That requires more explanation. What is "max" applied to a city, state or country? I would try to cleanse the data first and get the address into a normalized fashion.

Comment: Sorry, by "max" I meant literally just finding the city or state that repeats most often in that column.... similar to a basic SQL Query where you do an order by desc and group by a certain column.... oh well.... I don't know much about "cleansing" the database, as I 'm just an intern  and this is at a big company and someone else created the db and I don't have that many privileges, but i'll see what I can do here .... :(

Comment: So basically you want all rows that belong to the most frequently occurring city/state/country?

Comment: If `data isn't formatted the same at all times` you are out of luck. How would you know what's what?